# CSS won't work in email body

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, email

I'm sending a mail after pressing a button on my website and the body I'm sending in this mail is made with HTML and CSS because I need some formatting in there. The problem now is that not all of the CSS is working, I also enabled HTML in the mail so this is not the problem. It's mainly coloring and padding in a table, that's not working. When testing it on a whole new project the HTML and CSS works.

I'm using C# and ASP.NET.

Here is the code I'm using:`

```
        lMessage.Subject = "Versandformular";

        lMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

        lMessage.Body = "<html>" +
                            "<head>" +
                            "    <title>Versandformular</title>" +
                            "    <style>" +
                            "        body {" +
                            "            font-family: Verdana;" +
                            "        }" +
                            "        .artikel > table td, .artikel > table th, .artikel > table {" +
                            "            border: 1px;" +
                            "            border-style: solid;" +
                            "            border-collapse: collapse;" +
                            "            padding: 5px;" +
                            "            padding-right: 40px;" +
                            "            max-width: 350px;" +
                            "            text-align: left;" +
                            "        }" +
                            "        .versand {" +
                            "            border: none;" +
                            "        }" +
                            "        .artikel .versand {" +
                            "            width: 350px;" +
                            "        }" +
                            "    </style>" +
                            "</head>" +
                            "<body>" +
                            "    <h2>" +
                            "        Versandformular" +
                            "    </h2>" +
                            "    <div class='container'>" +
                            "        <div class='absender'>" +
                            "            <b>Absender:</b><br />" +
                            "            John Doe<br />" +
                            "            Some street<br />" +
                            "            Some city <br />" +
                            "           01234 / 567890" +
                            "        </div>" +
                            "        <br />" +
                            "        <div class='empfaenger'>" +
                            "            <b>Empfänger</b><br />" +
                            "            Max Mustermann GmbH & Co. KG<br />" +
                            "            Max Mustermann<br />" +
                            "            01234 / 5678910<br />" +
                            "            max.mustermann@mail.de<br />" +
                            "            Musterstraße 123<br />" +
                            "            12345 Musterstadt<br />" +
                            "            Deutschland<br />" +
                            "            Bundesstaat: Keine Angabe<br />" +
                            "            Bemerkungen:<br />" +
                            "            <div class='empf-bemerkung'>" +
                            "            </div>" +
                            "        </div>" +
                            "        <br />" +
                            "        <div class='versand'>" +
                            "            <b>Versand</b>" +
                            "            <table>" +
                            "                <tr>" +
                            "                    <td>Versandart</td>" +
                            "                    <td>Dokumentsendung EU</td>" +
                            "                </tr>" +
                            "                <tr>" +
                            "                    <td>Versanddienst</td>" +
                            "                    <td>Standard</td>" +
                            "                </tr>" +
                            "                <tr>" +
                            "                    <td>Bemerkungen</td>" +
                            "                    <td>Irgendetwas was mit dem Versand zu tun hat</td>" +
                            "                </tr>" +
                            "                <tr>" +
                            "                    <td>Nächsten Lieferung beipacken?</td>" +
                            "                    <td>Ja</td>" +
                            "                </tr>" +
                            "                <tr>" +
                            "                    <td>Termin bis:</td>" +
                            "                    <td></td>" +
                            "                </tr>" +
                            "                <tr>" +
                            "                    <td>Warenkosten Zahlung</td>" +
                            "                    <td>Proforma</td>" +
                            "                </tr>" +
                            "                <tr>" +
                            "                    <td>Kostenträger</td>" +
                            "                    <td>Absender</td>" +
                            "                </tr>" +
                            "                <tr>" +
                            "                    <td>Kostenstelle</td>" +
                            "                    <td>IT</td>" +
                            "                </tr>" +
                            "                <tr>" +
                            "                    <td>Tracking angeforderdert?</td>" +
                            "                    <td>Ja</td>" +
                            "                </tr>" +
                            "            </table>" +
                            "        </div>" +
                            "        <br />" +
                            "        <div class='artikel'>" +
                            "            <b>Artikel</b>" +
                            "            <table>" +
                            "                <tr>" +
                            "                    <th>#</th>" +
                            "                    <th>ArtikelNr</th>" +
                            "                    <th>WarentarifNr</th>" +
                            "                    <th>Menge</th>" +
                            "                    <th>Preis</th>" +
                            "                    <th>Beschreibung</th>" +
                            "                </tr>" +
                            "                <tr>" +
                            "                    <td>1</td>" +
                            "                    <td>1234567890</td>" +
                            "                    <td>1234 5678</td>" +
                            "                    <td>5 Stk.</td>" +
                            "                    <td>5€</td>" +
                            "                    <td>Jede Menge Schrauben</td>" +
                            "                </tr> " +
                            "            </table>" +
                            "        </div>" +
                            "    </div>" +
                            "</body>" +
                            "</html>";`
```

These are the styles not working:

```
    border: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    max-width: 350px;
```

At the end I'm basically just adding the sender, the receiver and an PDF attachment if that matters. Also it's just filled with some Text to test it.
I only tested it in Internet Explorer and Outlook 2013 and 2010. Because I only need those.

Comment: Can you please clarify exactly which css lines are not working? Have you also tested different browsers and different mail clients?

Comment: One spelling error: "Vesandformular" should read "Ve**r**sandformular".

Comment: Ooh sry :D i will fix that soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't place CSS inside the HEAD tags in HTML Email, rather use the inline "style".
It is advised because most of the mail clients separate body and head portion of html email code.

Take a look at https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ it will guide you to the css you can display in the email body based on the email client you are using (Gmail, yahoo, outlook, etc.)

**EDIT:**
change:

```
.artikel > table td, .artikel > table th, .artikel > table
```

to

```
.artikel table td, .artikel table th, .artikel table
```

in the url it states that using ">" in selector doesn't work in Outlook. Html in http://jsfiddle.net/3gL29qhL/

Comment: I only need to use Outlook 2013 and 2010 and from your list I can tell that the ccs i used, should work in Outlook.  Thanks anyway for the link, I think that I can use this in the future :)